# Underline heading in org mode

Tags: org-mode, faces

I would like to customise the appearance of headings in org mode.
The goal is to reduce the need for so many different colours.

I used the function below to set colours for the headings.

```
(custom-theme-set-faces 'user
`(org-level-1 ((t (:foreground "#ffff00"))))
`(org-level-2 ((t (:foreground "#e0e0e0"))))
`(org-level-3 ((t (:foreground "#8f8f8f"))))
`(org-level-4 ((t (:foreground "#474747"))))
`(org-level-5 ((t (:foreground "#474747"))))
`(org-level-6 ((t (:foreground "#474747"))))
`(org-level-7 ((t (:foreground "#474747"))))
`(org-level-8 ((t (:foreground "#474747"))))
)
```

Is there a way to make the headings automatically appear underlined?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. For example

```
(custom-theme-set-faces 'user
`(org-level-1 ((t (:foreground "red" :underline "orange"))))
)
```